# How can I make a shortcut to the webcam?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, webcam

This is my webcam:
1.3M webCam (04f2:b1d8)  Aspire 5742
Model Name: AS5742. Windows 7 64-bit

It shows in device manager.
It works fine.
Drivers updated.

This is the problem:
It doesn't appear in devices and printers.
It doesn't appear in My Computer or Computer.
It doesn't appear in Start/All Programs.

Therefore I can't start the camera unless I'm using it with another programme such as Google hangouts, Skype, facebook etc. 
I've tried everything I couldn't find anything related to a similar issue.
I came across someone mentioning that he did a shortcut once it was in use by one of the programmes mentioned above.
I can't figure it out. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a shortcut to a hardware device. Shortcuts are used to provide convenient access to programs installed on the computer.

You've discovered that someone did just that, creating a shortcut to the software being used with the web cam.

One does not "start" a web camera unless one is using a program that makes use of the web camera, which then resolves the starting aspect of the question.

Consider that if you had a shortcut that "started" the web camera, what would it do? If the answer to that question is "display what the web camera sees," you are running a program that does that and uses the web camera as described above.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  It looks to me that I got it all mixed up and since someone mentioned the shortcut I got even more confused.  But what about these instructions:

Comment: How to record video from webcam?
Method 1 On Windows
Make sure that your webcam is attached to your computer. ...
Open Start. ...
Type in camera . ...
Click Camera. ...
Switch to recording mode. ...
Click the "Record" button. ...
Record your video. ...
Click the "Stop" button.

Comment: The instructions you've listed implies that the web cam has native or bundled software which would have been installed if the installation process was done from an installation package. A quick of the model information indicates that the computer would have a program called Crystal Eye. Another link in the search: https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/93589/crystal-eye-webcam-not-working#_ga=2.247986887.1110962782.1515701939-1687274939.1515701939 shows that some trouble arises with this camera when upgrades to windows 8 are performed. Some win7 updates may cause problems too.